# in MySql auto generate new table if condition meet

Tags: mysql

in MySql, how to make auto create new table on last day and every month?

if LAST_DAY = 2022-10-31 23:59:59

THEN

CREATE TABLE this-month ( ID int, Data1 varchar(255), Daya2 varchar(255), Daya3 varchar(255) );

Comment: It's probably worth describing *why* you want to do this, as there may be better solutions to whatever problem you're trying to solve.  Because this is pretty odd functionality to need.

Comment: You can use the Event Scheduler to create and execute dynamic SQL every month.